# Nested loop keeps adding the same element multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have 2 `arrays` which I am getting as a `string-array` and an `integer-array` as follows:

```
   val country= resources.getStringArray(R.array.country_array)
   val flags = resources.getIntArray(R.array.country_flag_array)
```

which are in my `strings.xml` as follows:

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>USA</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Canada</item>

</string-array>

<integer-array name="country_flag_array">
    <item>@drawable/flag_united_states_of_america</item>
    <item>@drawable/flag_france</item>
    <item>@drawable/flag_canada</item>

</integer-array>
```

I have a `data class` as follows to add the country flag and it's name to populate a `recyclerView`.

```
data class CountryObject(val flagImage : Int, val country: String)
```

I have this function to populate a `list` with the flags and country:

```
private fun addCountriesToList(country: Array<String>, flgs : IntArray) : List<CountryObject>{

        val listCountry= ArrayList<CountryObject>()

        for(c in country){
            for (f in flgs){
                listCountry.add(CountryObject(f,  c))
            }
        }

        return listCountry
    }
```

EDIT : ADDITIONAL CODE:

This is where I am saving the `addCountriesToList` function

```
   val listCountry : List<CountryObject> = addCountriesToList(country, flags)
```

I have another function which populates the recycler view (Which I know works)

```
setupLanguageList(rv_country, listCountry , 0)
```

I can populate the `recyclerView` with the country names, but each country name is populated with the size of the array and the image does not show. So since there are 3 countries, each country is populated 3 times.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated as to why the languages are showing like that but not the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing for each country to add the same country one time with each flag. What you need to do is just for each country add the matching index flag

```
val countryObjects = country.indexedMap { index, country ->
    CountryObject(flgs[index], country)
}
```

Here the map is an iterator that takes one argument (a function) which result will make the elements of a list. The function here is sugar syntaxed with a lambda and the arguments are the index of the current element and the element itself. The lambda is returning your `CountryObject` because the last declaration on a lambda is the return.

So in this case you can do this because you have a matching index for the country on strings and on integers. A better solution would be an enum.

```
enum class Country(val flagImage : Int, val country: String) {
    USA(/*the values here*/)
    //the other countries
}
```

Then you can use the enum directly like this `Country.values()`

Comment: Thank you so much for great explanation. Very helpful. I got it to display the individual countries. Any idea about why the image of the flag won't set? Could it be something regarding the data type?

Comment: I think you are doing something invalid `@` annotations are usually resolved as the name space indicates. Add a log and see what is the value from the array. Generally I would push for the `Enum` and use values from `R.`. Then you can use `ContextCompat` to pass it to the `data class` solved as a drawable

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to nest these loops because you only want one of each element from each loop. If you nest them, you are multiplying the number of results you get.

The way to fix this would be to iterate a single time by index:

```
for(i in 0 until min(country.size, flgs.size)) {
    listCountry.add(CountryObject(flgs[i], country[i]))
}
```

You can also use a shortcut: the `zip` function:

```
val listCountry = flgs.zip(country) { f, c -> CountryObject(f, c) }
```

or more succinctly:

```
val listCountry = flgs.zip(country, ::CountryObject)
```

Comment: Interesting, documentation indicates a shorthanded version as well, you could add it https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html

Comment: @cutiko Sorry, I'm not sure what you're pointing out there that I didn't mention.

Comment: There is a shorthan `listA zip listB` in the docs, I think it would add value to the answer

Comment: That would give you a list of Pairs, which is not what the OP wants.